# Power series and Taylor series

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

> Let $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be a $\cal C^\infty$ function.  Consider the power series $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n$$ and call $R$ its radius of convergence. Then, is it true that in $(-R,R)$ $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n\,?$$

If we call $g$ the function defined on $(-R,R)$ such that $g(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n$, then I know that $g$ is $\cal C^\infty$ on $(-R,R)$ and $\dfrac{g^{(n)}(0)}{n!}=\dfrac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$ for all $n$.  So I know that every derivative of $g$ and $f$ are equal in $0$.  But does it imply that $g=f$?

Comment: No. $f(x)=\exp(-1/x^2)$, $x\ne0$, $f(0)=0$ has the Maclaurin series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 0$.

Comment: If that were so, could we have nontrivial test functions?

Comment: @DanielFischer What is a nontrivial test function?

Comment: @Matteo A "test function" usually means an infinitely differentiable ($\mathcal{C}^\infty$) function with compact support. (For some things, one denotes other classes of functions as "test functions", but that one is the most common.) A nontrivial test function is a test function that is not identically $0$.